# Android Studio build NDK error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an android project.My project depends mupdf that use NDK.I have two NDK version in my computer.One downloaded from Android Studio, another downloaded from this site:[ndk download site](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html).My project depends the NDK which downloaded from site now.When I want to run my project in genymotion, I got this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:android:assembleDebug]
executing buildNative
executing cleanNative
:android:buildNative
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:gsso: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that jni/libgs.so exists  or that its path is correct   
make.exe: Entering directory `F:/Android_Studio_Project/HelloToone/android'
F:\ADT\android-ndk-r10e\build\core\prebuilt-library.mk
Error:(45) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
make.exe: Leaving directory `F:/Android_Studio_Project/HelloToone/android'
:android:buildNative FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'F:\ADT\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.809 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

How to slove this error? Thank you.

Comment: So your BuildNative gradle task runs the wrong instance of ndk-build?

Comment: I don't know.I just downloaded NDK and mupdf resource code.

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](http://twiki.ghostscript.com/do/view/MuPDF/GhostProof) to set up your **libgs.so**?

Comment: I downloaded mupdf from this site:[link](http://www.mupdf.com/downloads/). I downloaded the item named "mupdf-1.8-source.tar.gz".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to GhostScript [instructions](http://twiki.ghostscript.com/do/view/MuPDF/GhostProof), you need to **libgs.so** separately.

You can either download a prebuilt library from http://ghostscript.com/~robin/libgs.so, or build it from sources at http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=user/robin/ghostpdl.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/android_mupdf_gs_so.

Alternatively, you can edit **build.gradle** file and remove `' SUPPORT_GPROOF=1'` from **buildNative** command line.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I got a another error:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':android:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'F:\ADT\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

I just remove `SUPPORT_GPROOF = 1` in build.gradle file.

Comment: Start with running `ndk-build` from command line. Try to run `ndk-build clean all`, and post the output if there is any failure.

Comment: When I run `ndk-build` from command line, I got this:`Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is al
r static libraries[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : mupdf <= mupdf.c
In file included from jni/mupdf.c:16:0:
../../include/mupdf/pdf.h:6:34: fatal error: mupdf/pdf/name-table
e or directory
 #include "mupdf/pdf/name-table.h"
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 1`

Comment: Thank you very much.My project is running.